# Shunt + hall: any advantages from combining those two?

Tags: current-measurement, amperage

Are there any devices that combine shunt resistor and Hall effect to measure the current with better precision?

Or, do I understand correctly that shunt is better in all aspects except of the heat dissipation, as suggested [here](https://www.knick-international.com/en/blog/2019/shunt-resistor-versus-hall-effect-technology/) and a need of taking care of the isolation separately?

Note, that this is not a duplicate of the [questions shunt vs hall](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123117/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-shunt-resistor-vs-a-hall-effect-sensor) but a question about combining those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globally, shunt is better, as long as the voltage drop / power dissipation in the shunt resistor is not an issue (nor the absence of isolation)

If you combine both, you already have all the cons of the shunt, so I can't see much use for reading out the hall sensor that is usually less accurate.

So if you plan to use both for the same measurement, I don't see any pro to do so, except redundancy : for example, if you fear that in case of an over current event (short circuit) your shunt resistor might fail close (ie become shorted, causing a 0A reading), then the hall sensor might still allow you to detect the problem and shut down your system).

Or you could decide to use them for different measurements, for example :

- for a motor controler (H bridge), measure the current to the ground with a shunt, but also measure the current directly on the wire going to the motor with a hall sensor (it's hard to do at that place with a shunt, and it gives you information about the current in the free-wheeling diodes)
- in an use-case where you mainly care about measuring precisely small currents, but sometimes you have far bigger currents for which you need less accuracy : use an amplifier with a high gain on the shunt (that will saturate at higher currents), and the hall sensor for the higher currents. NB : in this case, personally, I would rather use 2 amplifiers with different gain on the same shunt resistor.

Comment: Perfect, the second example is the use case I was thinking about - for example for measuring near zero current with high precision (for BMS Coulomb counting) for most of the time and occasionally measuring high current when system is in use. Then shunt could be used to calibrate Hall when the current is low.

Comment: well, you can do it that way, but once you already have the shunt, it's easier to just add one more op-amp (or just use one with 2 inputs) and 2 more resistors to get 2 different gains, one to sens low currents, the other one higher currents. So the only case I, personally, would think to use one of each for the same measurement would be for redundancy in safety critical applications.